# Find div in repeater, and change it's style element

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html, asprepeater

I have a repeater object that looks like the following

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptSpecialNotes" runat="server">
                    <headerTemplate><ol type="A"></HeaderTemplate>
                    <itemtemplate>
                                <li>
                                </li>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpSpecialNotesRepeater" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                            <ContentTemplate>

                                    <div id="specialNotes" name='<%# Eval("itemId") %>' runat="server">
                                        <asp:imagebutton runat="server"  width="20" class="floatLeft" id="specialNotesItem" imageurl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>'  commandname="specialNotesImageChange" commandargument='<%# Eval("itemId") %>'></asp:imagebutton>
                                        <span class="subject"><p><%# eval("Subject") %></p></span>
                                        <br /><br />
                                        <p><%# Eval("AgendaNote")%></p>
                                        <br />
                                    </div>

                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID ="followAlongControl" EventName ="Tick" />
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        <asp:Repeater id="specialNotesAttachmentsRepeater" OnItemCommand="specialNotesAttachmentRepeater_ItemCommand" runat="server" datasource='<%# Container.DataItem.Row.GetChildRows("attachmentRelation") %>' >
                            <itemtemplate>
                                <br />
                                <a href='<%# Container.DataItem("attachmentPath") %>'><%# Container.DataItem("attachmentName") %></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                </itemtemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </itemtemplate>
                    <footerTemplate></ol></FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

I want to change the background color of the div 'specialNotes' depending on the imageurl of the image button. So if it's checked, the div would be grey, if not, then i'd leave it blank.

Is there a way to do this in the code-behind with VB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to "Find" the div after the page has loaded, you can do this as it is getting bound. I imagine that when you say "if it's checked" that you refer to the imagebutton acting as a checkbox, and you want to change the color depending on the location(path) of the image. So I would this in the div:

```
<div style='<%# doColor(Eval("ImageUrl")) %>'>
    Content in the div
</div>
```

and then this in the code behind:

```
Public Function doColor(img As Object) As String
    If img.ToString() = "MyPath" Then
        Return "background-color:red"
    Else
        Return "background-color:green"
    End If
End Function
```

that way if the ImageUrl equals "MyPath" the background of your div will be red, otherwise it will be green.

Comment: I couldn't get that rigged up properly. I think i'm particularly perplexed on where I'm firing the event? Does doColor fire every time the div is created? or do I fire it in the same place I do my databind? Could you perhaps provide a bit more instruction? I must be overlooking something...

Comment: That is being called everytime the div is created. You don't have to do anything wherever you bind the repeater.

Comment: Worked exactly how I need it to. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Add a `runat="server"` to your div tag. Then your code behind, you can access that div using:

`udpSpecialNotesRepeater.FindControl("div")`

on your DataBound event.

It is alot easier to do it in jQuery though. You can just grab id of the div `$("#specialNotes")` and use the `.attr` function to change its background.

Comment: but you wouldn't be able to grab "specialNotes" because it's not rendered as that, it's rendered as "specialNotes_01" or w.e, after the repeater databind. I don't know what div I'm going to grab before hand. Add to that, you can't set the id to a #eval("itemId") there, because it's syntax would be incorrect.

Comment: That means it is being rendered as an asp.net control. To access an asp.net control, you can use it is "IdOfControl.ClientId". In your case, it is specialNotes.ClientId.

Answer (score 0):

can use:

```
Control divControl=e.Item.FindControl("divControl");
```